# Delete row from a column that is unnamed or blank using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to delete a row from a column that is unnamed or blank using pandas.
I would like to delete the row that contains 'id'

**Data**

```
        a   b   c
date    21  22  23
id          
aa      2   3   4
bb      1   2   3
cc      5   5   5
```

**Desired**

```
        a   b   c
date    21  22  23
aa      2   3   4
bb      1   2   3
cc      5   5   5
```

**Doing**

```
df[df[""].str.contains("id")==False]
```

or

```
df.drop(1)
```

However, the action is not executed and I do not get the desired result.
I am actively researching this. Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: The columns with date, id, ... is an index or a real column?

Comment: Looks like that first colum is the index. You can just do this: df=df[df.index!='id']

Comment: Real column @Corralien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dropna`:

```
>>> df.dropna(how='all', axis=0)
         a     b     c
date  21.0  22.0  23.0
aa     2.0   3.0   4.0
bb     1.0   2.0   3.0
cc     5.0   5.0   5.0
```

**Update**

If the first column is not an index but a real column with an empty name, maybe you should use this version:

```
>>> df[df.loc[:, df.columns.str.len().astype(bool)].notna().any(axis=1)]

            a     b     c
0  date  21.0  22.0  23.0
2    aa   2.0   3.0   4.0
3    bb   1.0   2.0   3.0
4    cc   5.0   5.0   5.0
```

Or more simple, if your unnamed column is the first:

```
>>> df[df.iloc[:, 1:].notna().any(axis=1)]
            a     b     c
0  date  21.0  22.0  23.0
2    aa   2.0   3.0   4.0
3    bb   1.0   2.0   3.0
4    cc   5.0   5.0   5.0
```

Comment: Thank you. I used 2nd soln. I am getting:
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with Index, not MultiIndex

Comment: What is the output of `df.columns` and `df.index`, please?

Comment: ok will update / edit post and provide tomo

Comment: Just to be sure, can you try `df.rename_axis(None)`?

Comment: wow this worked @Corralien. This was a little tricky, but after doing : df.rename_axis(None) and then  df[df.iloc[:, 1:].notna().any(axis=1)], this did the trick! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Regardless, you have a row with space. Way out is to query df for such rows and filter them out. Space, indicates a dtype `object`. I would

```
df.where((df!=' ')).dropna()



        a     b     c
date  21.0  22.0  23.0
aa     2.0   3.0   4.0
bb     1.0   2.0   3.0
cc     5.0   5.0   5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command, it will drop all column which contain any null values

```
data = data.dropna()
```